# Angular - How to access the nativeElement in click handler

Tags: angular, elementref

Maybe only a "stylish" but nonetheless...

I've the following which is working:

```
// Template
<div *ngFor="let media of period.media">
    .
    .
    .
    <button #btn (click)="onDeleteClick(btn)" [attr.media-id]="media.ID">
        {{'DELETE' | translate}}
    </button>
</div>

//component.ts
    this.period.media = [
        {id: 123}, {id: 456}, ...
    ];
    .
    .
    .
    onDeleteClick(elem) {
        console.log(elem._elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('media-id'));
    }
```

It works (`the console shows 123, 456,...`) but accessing the nativeElelement using the _elemntRef sounds like a hack (underscore denotes Private property, like _privateVar, isn't it).

So what would be a more elegant way to access the nativeElement or, even better, its 'media-id' attribute?

Thanks a lot for any hint.

**EDIT**

The answer to this question is in the comments from **user184994** and **JB Nizet**. Since they both addressed the problem correctly I cannot set the "accepted answer" flag since it can be assigned to only once.

Therefore I'm editing my question as acknowledgement of this.

Comment: You could always pass it in to your `onDeleteClick`, like so `onDeleteClick(btn, media.ID)`

Comment: The view should be derived from the model, not vice-versa. Pass the media, not a reference to the button. And get the media ID using media.id: `(click)="onDeleteClick(media)"`. The media-id attribute on the button is useless.

Comment: @user184994 and @ JB_Nizet. Wow, I feel so stupid! It was sooo simple! I would say to both user184994 and JB_Nizet to post your comments as an answer. I wish it was possible would the check both as the accepted, but iI fear it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is already given but I would like to add one more point and answer it.
you're using button, ***for most browsers the default type of button is submit.*** 
and ***if try to delete it will get submitted***,if you do not want it you can change it's type to `type = "button"` .

```
<div *ngFor="let media of period.media">
    <button type = "button" #btn 
  (click)="onDeleteClick(media)"
   [attr.media-id]="media.ID">{{'DELETE' | translate}}</button>
</div>
```

additionally if you want ***you can pass only id*** if you need or want, just use `onDeleteClick(media.id)` ***this is better in terms of performance***. You can remove template varibale if you don not required it.
//component.ts

```
this.period.media = [
    {id: 123}, {id: 456}, ...
];
.
.
.
onDeleteClick(media) {
    console.log(media.id);
}
```

if you are passing only id then need to change syntax like

```
  onDeleteClick(id) {
        console.log(id);

    }
```

Comment: @'v8 sagar' Thanks for the additional detail. It is very useful in general, but in my case I need the whole set of data associated with media. Furthermore, I will need to pass additional params to the click handler. I'm implementing a kind of "cards" that can be added/removed dinamically. Thanks in any case for the clarification.